# Kivy - Disable touchpad touchscreen-like behavior

Tags: input, kivy, touchpad

I need some help with programming a simple kivy app. I have the problem, that kivy 'matches' my laptops touchpad to the screen. i.e. I tap at the left center of the touchpad and kivy does not send a mouseclick at the current mouse position, but at the left center of the screen. This behavior is quite annoying, because it results in a 'clicking-interference'. Is there a way to fix this? It seems like a kind of touchscreen input is enabled. (maybe change this in the kivy config?)
I just want a normal mouse behavior. :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may get more answers for this kind of question on the kivy discord channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help on the kivy discord.
To fix this I commented out the probesysfs line in the kivy config (~/.kivy/config.ini).

Comment: This does work! The very existence of such a config surprised me a lot. I never installed my Kivy system- or user wide; strictly virtual environments. How am I supposed to manage it with a packaged app, for instance?