# Kivy: laptop touch pad - mouse cursor move

Tags: python, kivy, desktop-application, gesture, touchpad

My problem is simple and certainly isn't any news: I can manage my Kivy desktop app with a mouse pretty reasonably. Unfortunately, touch pad is a different story: a single finger move is interpreted as a swipe so there's no way to just move the mouse cursor where it's needed. Google isn't very cooperative; maybe I don't know the keywords?

The desktop is KDE on Linux.

Is there a way to make a Kivy desktop app respond to the touch pad the way ordinary desktop apps do?

[Input management](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/inputs.html) looks close, but low level. I'm sorry, I'm new to Kivy.

Comment: do you mean a touchpad on a Windows laptop computer?  or on a mac computer?  or some other operating system or device?  on my Windows based Kivy applications the mouse works the same as my laptops touchpad.  but this of course can depend on the code and the configurations.

Comment: It's Linux, KDE

Comment: I'm glad to see you found your answer.  There are many options for how to get a mouse cursor in linux depending on the system and whether or not you are booting the desktop or only the console.  this topic comes up a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60890388/kivy-disable-touchpad-touchscreen-like-behavior): comment out `probesysfs` line in `~/.kivy/config.ini`.

```
...
[input]
mouse = mouse
#%(name)s = probesysfs
...
```